# error unable communicate with master

Tags: ros, roscore, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to setup a workstation to work with a Turtlebot.

I've followed the tutorial here : wiki.ros.org/Robots/Turtlebot/Network%20Setup

Robot IP is : 192.168.0.152
Workstation IP is 192.168.0.122

In .bashrc
I set up ROS_MASTER_URI in both bashrc at this value : http://192.168.0.152:11311
Both Hostname are set up with the IP of the machine

I can ping in both ways.

Roscore is launched on the robot and rostopic return "/rosout" and "/rosout_agg"
But still when I launch "rostopic list" on the workstation, it doesn't work and returns "Unable to connect with master"

Has someone any leads that we could follow please?

Thank you :D

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318389/error-unable-communicate-with-master/) by [gautier](https://answers.ros.org/users/40444/gautier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-03-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2019-03-12**:
Have you set the IP of the workstation as ROS id? If workstation isn't properly identified, roscore can't connect it to the topic.

"export ROS_IP=192.168.0.122" in the bashrc file on the workstation?

**Comment by [gautier](https://answers.ros.org/users/40444/gautier/) on 2019-03-13**:
hello,
thanks for your answer but the bashrc file already have "export ROS_IP=192.168.0.122"
have you other ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

got it !! it was the firewall of the machine link to the robot thanks for your help anyway

---

Originally posted by [gautier](https://answers.ros.org/users/40444/gautier/) with karma: 16 on 2019-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0